# samsung galaxy tab 2 is not showing for debugging android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using samsung galaxy tab2 gt-p3100 for android application debuging on eclipse on windows. I have installed the updated version of kies.and i have enabled the usb debuging option inside setting.also i have started several times eclipse and also the tab still the deivce is not showing for debuging option in eclipse.i have another samsung phone and for that i am able to debug the andoid app.Please help me.

Comment: Could you tell what shows `adb devices` in console?

Comment: it is not showing if i connect tab and check for adb devices.?

Comment: Please see OlejkaKL's ans in below link it has solved my problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492073/android-sdk-eclipse-samsung-galaxy-tab-2-how-to-recognize-devices/16492230#16492230

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes.Restart your PC and check.Are you using windows 7?If so wait until device finds the driver

Comment: Yes i did restaring several times but this device is not showing in eclipse.

Comment: When I first connected my device in windows 7, I also faced the same issue.I left my device connected for 15 min.It found the driver update and I could get my device in eclipse debug mode.Can u see the device icon in your task bar?