# android sdk eclipse, samsung galaxy tab 2, How to recognize devices

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

I'm trying to develop on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with eclipse and android sdk. I've already installed Samsung Kies and turned on USB debugging on my device.

It looks like eclipse didn't know the new samsung driver. Did I forget something? What should be the windows pilot of the device? I think is the samsung pilot. Should I be able to create virtual samsung at this step? What is the correct url for the samsung add on site?

I'm on windows 8. I'm using Eclipse Juno and adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219

Comment: Yes normally you should be able to debug on your device. I once had this problem, restarting device solved it.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to run cmd, then go to platform-tools root, and run the following command:
***adb devices***
This will list all attached devices and tell you if your samsung phone is recognized by Android Debug Bridge, if it is not then search for another driver for your phone and try again.

Comment: Thanks. The device is recognised by android debug bridges. The adb devices detect the devices. What could be the problem with the android device manager

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you try this.

Unplug your device. Install this drivers. After installation plug it in again.
It should recognize your device.

Link :  http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I705MKAVZW

Comment: THnaks for the direct link for the driver (without the samsung tool). But it doesn't work. How eclipse know about the device ? It ask windows ?

Answer (score 3):

If Windows recognises the USB mass storage on your device, what you can do, is go to `Device Manager`, Right-click on `My Computer` > `Manage` > `Device Manager`, find your device, should say not recognised or something like that, click `Update driver software` then click `Browse my computer for driver software` then click `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`, you should end up with a list, click `Show all devices` or something like that. Then search for your manufacturer in the list, in your case `Samsung`, click on manufacturer and find Android USB debug or something like that (it's a certificate) then install that.

Restart your `adb` in Eclipse, to do so, go to `devices tab`, (to get to it, click `Window` > `Show view` and find `Devices` if not in that list, then check in `Other` list at the bottom. Click on arrow in image below, and select `restart adb` [image] . Finally restart Eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you can just accept the answer, so the thread is marked solved, that would be awesome...

Comment: Hi. Sorry i don't know how to do so :(. I need 15 reputation for vote up your anwser. Are there another way ?

Comment: Ohh, ok, nevermind, that's fine. You don't have to, it's just so that the thread is marked as solved, but if you can't accept the answer, that's not a problem. Glad I could help you though =]

Answer (score 0):

On a Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 you need to go to Settings -> Developer Options (scroll right down the list to the left), enable it in the top-right switch, then turn USB Debugging on.

Running adb devices will then show your device if you have the Samsung Mobile USB Composite Devices driver installed (through Kies or otherwise).